# SQL Server Replication - Adding a new stored procedure - How to get it to replicate?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, replication

I have a SQL Server 2005 Database which uses merge replication.

I have added four new stored procedures on the publisher end, but they haven't replicated.

The publication property "Subscription Options" - "Replicate schema changes" is set to True.

How can I get easily get these tables replicated without having to send new snapshots to all of the subscribers?

Comment: When choosing the objects i.e., tables to replicate did you check off all of your stored procedures as well to be included in the replication?

Comment: Yes, but this stored procedure was added after I setup the initial merge replication publication.

Answer (score 1):

I found this bit of code, perhaps it will help.

```
create table table2(pk int not null primary key, charcol char(20))
GO
sp_addarticle 'paul','table2','table2'
GO
sp_refreshsubscriptions 'paul'
GO
sp_addsubscription 'paul','table2',@@servername,'paulsub'
GO
```

Adding the article and then running the snapshot agent seems to reinit the entire publication.